# I can't use SearchView

Tags: java, android, searchview

[image]

I have a problem when I try using **SearchView** in **Android Studio**. It's not working when I add **SearchView**, but when I remove it, my application runs normally. When I rebuild this project. There is a notification:

```
"$ adb shell am start -n
"com.example.nguyenkiemhung.myhomework/
com.example.nguyenkiemhung.myhomework.WelcomeActivity" -a
android.intent.action.MAIN -c 
android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Client not ready yet..Connected to process 4038 
on device samsung-gt_i8552-cab17026"
```

Can you tell me what problem in here? Thank you!

Comment: post your `manifest.xml`

Answer (score 0):

This might be because you haven't defined your search view in the manifest. You have to declare your activity as searchable; something like this:

```
<activity android:name=".WelcomeActivity" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
               android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
</activity>
```

For more info, checkout the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html)